# how to disable jMockit instantiation for specific Robolectric tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, jmockit, robolectric, android-testing

many of my Android unit tests are written with Robolectric,
but it is very limiting and I want to use jMockit for some tests.

the problem is that the Robolectric test runner fails whenever jMockit is instantiating the classes.

I found out that its possible to tell jMockit to instantiate only annotated classes by settings the system property "jmockit-mockParameters" to "annotated" - http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/source/detail?r=2066

I'm using Intellij IDEA and added to the test run configuration VM options `-Djmockit-mockParameters=annotated` but it doesn't work..

how can I properly set this system property ?

Comment: I use mockito and don't have issues with mocking. Sorry for oftopic

Comment: I'm using Mockito with Robolectric as well. jMockit is different as it allows mocking of static objects. I want to use it to mock Android stuff whenever there are testability issues with Robolectric (or testing something becomes too complicated)

Comment: What kind of failure do you see?

Comment: I found out that its a known issue, maybe someone has a solution - http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/issues/detail?id=237

Comment: are you sure you have to do this? i'm using JMockit 1.8 and everything seems perfectly compatible